# Разница между typedef и using при объявлении в классе алиасов типов

Tags: c++, clion, alias

Пытаюсь понять разницу между областью видимости алиасов типов в классе, объявленных в `private` и `public` секциях:

```
class A {
    using PRI = int;
    typedef int PRI2;

public:
    using PUB = int;
    typedef int PUB2;
}; 

int main() {
    A::PUB  a; // OK
    A::PUB2 b; // OK
    A::PRI  c; // IDE видит этот тип, но ошибка компиляции 
    A::PRI2 d; // IDE НЕ видит этот тип + ошибка компиляции
}
```

При наборе `A::` мне предлагают подстановку `A::PRI`, `A::PUB` и `A::PUB2`, но не `A::PRI2`.

Это баг или связано с разными реализациями `using` и `typedef`?

---

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-14372
вот добавил в багтрекер, может исправят, хотя это не критично, конечно

Comment: [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10747810/2881286) говорят что это одно и то же.

Comment: Вы формулируйте корректнее. Это проблема никак **не языка**, и области видимости с точки зрения языка. Это только в какой-то вашей конкретной IDE, и не более того. Так что я бы обязательно добавил тэг, указывающий среду...

Comment: @Harry добавил.

Comment: Очевидно, это недопиленность clion вылезает... По возможности попробуйте использовать другую IDE.

Comment: @VTT тогда стоит в багтрекер им написать, если это точно баг

Comment: Очевидно, что у CLion не всё в порядке с `using`, их intellisense не понимает, что это — пишите им в багтрекер, а ссылку тут киньте.

Comment: Что "видит" и что "не видит" IDE при наборе текста - это проблема текстового редактора IDE. Никакого отношения к языку это не имеет. Не надо пытаться на основе этого делать какие-то выводы о языковых областях видимости. В данном случае не наблюдается никакой разницы между `using` и `typedef`.